# $_GET in Case 'get'

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter's controller the `$_GET['variable']` not working in case `'GET'`
for Example:

```
case 'GET';
if(isset($_GET['variable'])){
//do somthing
}
```

After URL contains `?variable=1` the if condition always fails I don't know why?

Comment: What's the full code?

Comment: submit your full url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this in your `config.php` file
`$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;` and access query string parameters with `$this->input->get('variable')`

Answer (score 1):

for getting `$_GET` value in codeigniter you use:-

```
parse_str($_SERVER['variable'], $_GET);
```

and make sure this is true in your config.php file

```
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
```

and you must have to add

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use $this->input->post('var')

```
if($this->input->post('var')){
     //do somthing
}
```